# regex use for find word without space in mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb

i have a word like

> isabig

i need find this word in

> Elephant `is a big` animal

please give me a regex example for do that in mongodb.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One possible answer is to add an optional space between each character.

The regex would look like:

```
/i *s *a *b *i *g/
```

This roughly means after each character, allow 0 or more (`*`) space characters (). This will work but obviously gets tedious to write so you could do something like this:

```
var origString = 'thisisa';
var regexStr = origString.split('').join(' *');

db.collection.find({ field: { $regex: regexStr });
```